# What is the best equivalent for `ScheduledExecutorService` in C#?

Tags: java, c#, .net

I need the best equivalent for `ScheduledExecuterService` in C#, some blogs said `Timer` is used but I think its single thread while the `ScheduledExecuterService` is asynchronous thread pool.

Please your help.